# Any possibility to get Months and date for these string "next", "after", "coming", "one month later", "next one month", "after this month"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, date, bots

I have a list of holidays in json for the particular month, user is just asking "show the next month holidays", "display coming month holidays", "display next 2/two month holidays" etc like this i'm planning to give the choices for asking holidays, How do I find the holidays for specified month in the JSON object
I don't know, is this possible using Javascript date object or not.. 
Below is my holidays JSON object

```
 {
"Month": "Jan",
"Date": 26,
"Day": "Thursday",
"Holiday": "Republic Day"
},
{
"Month": "Mar",
"Date": 13,
"Day": "Monday",
"Holiday": "Holi day"
},{
"Month": "Apr",
"Date": 14,
"Day": "Friday",
"Holiday": "Good Friday"
},
{
"Month": "May",
"Date": 1,
"Day": "Monday",
"Holiday": "May Day"
},{
"Month": "June",
"Date": 26,
"Day": "Monday",
"Holiday": "Ramzan(Eid-ul-fitr)***"
},
{
"Month": "Aug",
"Date": 7,
"Day": "Monday",
"Holiday": "Rksha Bandhan"
},
{
"Month": "Aug",
"Date": 14,
"Day": "Monday",
"Holiday": "Janmashtami"
}
```

Please anybody help me to trace the json object for user value..
Im developing bot for showing the holidays for user..

Comment: You seem to want some sort of natural language parser (which is one half of [*natural language processing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing)) to determine what the user is asking. That's a lot more complex than parsing a distinct set of tokens like "show", "next", "last", "month", "week" and so on.

Comment: @RobG Yes you'r right.. any examples for this? Please help me solve this

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can first cache the month names to match those in your JSON:

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
```

Get the next and following months:

```
var next = new Date();
next.setMonth(next.getMonth()+1); // If it is Nov now, expect to be Dec

var following = new Date();
following.setMonth(following.getMonth()+2); // If it is Nov now, expect to be Jan
```

Then iterate over your JSON to get values matching:

```
for(i=0; i < holidays.length; i++){
  if(holidays[i].Month == monthNames[next.getMonth()]){
     //holidays[i] is a holiday in next month
  }
  else if(holidays[i].Month == monthNames[following.getMonth()]){
    //holidays[i] is a holiday in following month
  }
}
```

You will also need to assign your JSON to holidays variable for this example, i.e.:

```
var holidays = [
  {
    "Month": "Jan",
    "Date": 26,
    "Day": "Thursday",
    "Holiday": "Republic Day"
  },
  {
    "Month": "Mar",
    "Date": 13,
    "Day": "Monday",
    "Holiday": "Holi day"
  },
  {
    "Month": "Apr",
    "Date": 14,
    "Day": "Friday",
    "Holiday": "Good Friday"
  },
];
```

### UPDATE

To filter from a user choice add a field for them, I will use select box as example:

```
<select name="filter" id="dateFilters">
  <option selected> - Select Filter - </option>
  <option value="next">Next Month</option>
  <option value="following">Following Month</option>
  <option value="next2">Next 2 Months</option>
</select>
```

Then use the selected value to decide what to show:

```
var e = document.getElementById("dateFilters");
var selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

switch(selected){
  case 'next':
    var next = new Date();
    next.setMonth(next.getMonth()+1);

    var targets = [monthNames[next.getMonth()]];
    break;

  case 'following':
    var following = new Date();
    following.setMonth(following.getMonth()+2);

    var targets = [monthNames[following.getMonth()]];
    break;

  case 'next2':
    var next = new Date();
    next.setMonth(next.getMonth()+1);

    var following = new Date();
    following.setMonth(following.getMonth()+2);

    var targets = [monthNames[next.getMonth()], monthNames[following.getMonth()]];
    break;
}
```

Then the iterator becomes:

```
for(i=0; i < holidays.length; i++){
  for(ii=0; ii < targets.length; ii++){
    if(holidays[i].Month == targets[ii]){
      // holidays[i] contains holiday to be shown
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not for next month.. Its user choices.. it may like "show the next month holidays", "display coming month holidays", "display next 2/two month holidays" , "Previous month", "next year holidays" ..

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar - I have updated my answer with a solution for you.

Comment: But its user wish.. I am allowing him to type anything for holidays.. Its not like select options we are providing.. Any hints for getting all possible texts like  "show the next month holidays", "display coming month holidays", "display next 2/two month holidays" , "Previous month", "next year holidays" from this and make array then find the holidays..

Comment: Use `strtotime()` server side to get a timestamp from the string? If result is in the past, filter from then until now, and if in the future show from now until the result. Ideally include a timestamp in the JSON (Could be added to JSON object server side if holidays is user data too?) which can then be used to filter from and to?

Comment: What about 3 fields when client defines the options, one for the user facing value, one for number of past months to show and one for number of future months to show. You can then offset current month by -(number of past months) and +(number of future months), 0, 0 for this month, 1, 0 for last month, 0, 12 for next year etc? Whichever solution you opt for, computing a date range from a user entered string is bound to fall over at some point whichever way you compute it.